# (iOS-like) overscroll on ScrollView not working in Android?

Tags: android, ios, scrollview, android-scrollview, overscroll

I'm trying to get my scrollview to have the *"overscroll"* effect as there is in iOS. I have tried two things with little to no success:

**First try:**

I used [This](https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor) , like:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
OverScrollDecoratorHelper.setUpOverScroll(scrollView);
```

However, it introduces some problems. When scrolling (Both up or down) , the textviews in my scrollview scrolled over outside the scrollview area, and I did not find a way to stop this. Any ideas on this? (Photo below to help explain)

[image]

**Second try:**

I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29) and tried it like:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView2);
scrollView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS);
```

However nothing happened here, the ScrollView remained the same.

Do you have any idea on how to solve any of these two tries? Or another way to implement the *overscroll* effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to scroll over you can use

```
View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
```

Here is reference for android documentation:
[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29)